# \forcsvlist and expansion

Tags: expansion

I've got an expansion issue with the following code:

```
\def\sizes{huge, LARGE, Large, large, normalsize, small, footnotesize, scriptsize, tiny}
\forcsvlist\sampletext{\sizes}
```

My problem is that `\sizes` should be expanded before being passed to `\forcsvlist`, otherwise `\sampletext` will simply receive the list and not know how to parse it.

How can I make it so that `\sizes` is expanded?

**Note:** Putting the list hardcoded in the `\sampletext` call works, but I don't want to do that because I might override `\sizes` with other values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the standard way:

```
\expandafter\forcsvlist\expandafter\sampletext\expandafter{\sizes}
```

The first `\expandafter` expands the second one, which in turn expands the third and this last does the job, expanding `\sizes`. The primitive `\expandafter` expands to nothing, after having caused the expansion of the second token after it; just jump over one token, when checking the action of `\expandafter`. It's a bit more complicated when there are arguments, but `\expandafter` and `\sizes` don't take them. The expansion performed by `\expandafter` is only one step: after

```
\def\y{\z} \def\z{a}
```

saying

```
\expandafter\x\y
```

is like saying

```
\x\z
```

In your case the three `\expandafter` commands vanish, but TeX now has

```
\forcsvlist\sampletext{huge,LARGE,...}
```

and continues expanding from here.

Another trick is

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\forcsvlist\noexpand\sampletext{\sizes}}\x
```

which works because the expansion of `\sizes` consists of characters; it wouldn't if `\sizes` had been defined as

```
\def\sizes{\huge,\LARGE,...}
```

Comment: `\expandafter` is still something a bit hard for me to grasp. I don't get why I have to use 3 of them.

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: Any explanation about the "Another trick", I don't quite understand them, thanks.

Comment: @ollydbg23 This defines `\x` to expand to `\endgroup\forcsvlist{<full expansion of \sizes>}`; executing `\x` will close the group started with `\begingroup` and do `\forcsvlist`.

Comment: @egreg thanks, why `\noexpand` is put before `{\sizes}`? I generally think I need not a `\noexpand` before `{\sizes}`, because I can let `\edef` to expand the `{\sizes}` to `{<full expansion of \sizes>}`.

Comment: @ollydbg23 Oh! That `\noexpand`! Well, it was supposed to be in front of `\sampletext`. Thanks for noting.