# Problem if csv list is stored in macro for later use with \forcsvlist

Tags: macros, etoolbox

I need to store a csv list for later use in the end code part of an environment. 
Can somebody explain me what's going wrong in the following example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand*\mycsv{1,2,3}
\newcommand*\printnumbers[1]{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{one, }{}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{two, }{}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{three, }{}
}
\newcommand*\doprint[1]{\forcsvlist\printnumbers{#1}}
\begin{document}
\doprint{1,2,3} % does work

\doprint{\mycsv} % does not work
\end{document}
```

If the list is stored in the macro, it seems to be no longer a list for `\forcsvlist` but a single token. Any other solution which solves my problem?

Comment: Related/duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22393/forcsvlist-and-expansion

Comment: @egreg Yep '\newcommand*\doprint[1]{\expandafter\forcsvlist\expandafter\printnumbers\expandafter{#1}}' does the trick. Thank you! Oh, i hate TeX ;-)

Comment: You can hide that in a `\xforcsvlist` macro: `\newcommand{\xforcsvlist}[2]{\expandafter\forcsvlist\expandafter#1\expandafter{#2}}` and then `\newcommand{\doprint}[1]{\xforcsvlist\printnumbers{#1}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `#1` can't be all of `1`, `2`, `3` at the same time, there is an inefficiency in OP's `\printnumbers`. Here is an alternative solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{loops}
\newcommand*\comma{\ifforeachlastitem.\else, \fi}
\newcommand*\doprint[1]{%
  \newforeach [expand list once] \x in {#1} {%
    \skvifcase\skvxifstrcmpTF\x
      {1}{one\comma}
      {2}{two\comma}
      {3}{three\comma}
    \elsedo
      \@latex@error{\string\doprint: no match}\@ehd
    \endif
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\doprint{1,2,3}
\par
\doprint{} % empty list
\par
\newcommand*\mylist{1,2,3}
\doprint{\mylist}
\end{document}
```

This solution can be generalized to other list types beyond `{1,2,3}`.